# Converting an imported data frame from to a list of assigned variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have imported a text file as a data frame in R using read.table function. The data frame has two columns:

```
    V1    V2
1   a1  1.024e+06
2   a2  1.000e-01
3   a3  1.000e-04
```

with 500 rows. The first column is the name of the parameters from a1,a2,...,a500. The second column is the value of each parameter.

I want to convert this data frame into a list of assigned variables meaning`

```
a1  <- 1.024e+06
a2  <- 1.000e-01
a3  <- 1.000e-04
```

so that when calling by the name of the parameters, returns the value of assigned.

How can I do that in R?

Comment: Believe me, calling the name inside the dataframe is a better approach comparing to assigning. I mean call the variable names like  `data[data[,"V1"]=="a1","V2"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df){
  assign(df$V1[i],df$V2[i]) 
}
```

This is a terrible way to do write code though and you'll be much better of getting value of `a1` by

```
df[df$V1 == "a1","V2"]
```